# How do I add Remove() and .Add() in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

How do I can write a `.Remove(object data)` and `.Add(object data)` methods in my Repo/Controller logic when I am using in Entity Framework as the ORM? I generated Entity Model and everything works in my program, except for saving and removing entries from the database.

This is my code sample with the empty method placeholders:

```
class Projects
{
    public static List<TProjekty> GetAll()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        EntitiesModel em = DB.GetDB();

        List<TProjekty> projects = em.TProjekties.ToList();

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("GetAllProjects: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        return projects;
    }

    public static List<TProjekty> GetAllActiveOnly()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        EntitiesModel em = DB.GetDB();

        List<TProjekty> projects = em.TProjekties.Where(p => p.Aktualni == true).ToList();

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("GetAllProjects: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        return projects;
    }

    public void Add(object data)
    {
        //var item = Entry(data);
    }

    public void Delete(object data)
    {
        //var item = Entry(data);
    }

    public static void Save(TProjekty project)
    {
        if (project == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        EntitiesModel em = DB.GetDB();
        em.Add(project);
        em.SaveChanges();

        Checker.CheckAfterEverySave();
    }
}
```

The code is alright without any errors, but I have empty methods for the `Add` and the `Delete`, because I have no idea how should I write it. I have to use .Net framework 4.8 so I cant use DB option for .Net Core.

Comment: Hi, could you add some code ? it will be easier for the community to help u

Comment: Yea, just moment

Comment: it's because you are using object instead of a true type

Comment: I need to use it up to 80 times (each), to delete entry in the database or add a entry. But I have no idea how to write it without the .NET CORE (db)

Comment: Which line is causing the error? You need to give us a [mre], most of this code here is not necessary for us to help. Having said that, did you mean to write `em.TProjekties.Add(project)`?

Comment: I got no errors, I am sorry. I need a method so I can save everything to my Database, I am using it up to 90 different times. 

The code is alight without any errors, but I have empty methods for the Add and the Delete, because I have no idea how should I write it. I have to use .Net framework 4.8 so I cant use DB option for .Net Core. 

That is why I asked for help, I really need to know how to write Add() and Delete() method so it would work everywhere. 

Could you help me please? I can show you whatever part of code you want.

Comment: Sorry, we're not going to write code for you. We don't know the detailed specification to begin with and you should be able to find many examples of similar functions.

Comment: if you did db first, should be something like  context.YOURTABLE.Add(YOURDATA)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a typed interface for this, instead of trying to use a *boxed* object reference, in fact your code in `Save` is already doing the `Add` for you!

> This solution is not *best practice* and is only provided as a direct response to the specific question. The whole pattern of wrapping a `DbContext` in a detached way like this (detached because the `TPojeckty` instances returned from `Get` methods use a different `DbContext` instance to the data persisting methods.) is generally considered an anti-pattern, in many use cases (not all) it would be better for the calling logic to use the `DbContext` instance directly. You can see in this code, the `Add` and `Delete` more or less call the same methods in the `DbContext`.

```
public void Add(TProjekty project)
{
    EntitiesModel em = DB.GetDB();
    em.TProjektys.Add(project);
    em.SaveChanges();

    Checker.CheckAfterEverySave();
}

public void Delete(TProjekty project)
{
    EntitiesModel em = DB.GetDB();
    em.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    em.SaveChanges();

    Checker.CheckAfterEverySave();
}
```

> **NOTE:** This code is assuming that the `DbSet<>` in your `DbContext` for the `TProjekty` type is called `em.TProjektys`. Please update the code with a reference that matches the name of your `DbSet` before executing. It may also be the singular or proper plural forms of either: `em.TProjekty` or `em.TProjekties`

> **Also:** both of these methods are persisting the changes to the database, that is why I am calling out to your `Checker.CheckAfterEverySave();` in this solution.

As mentioned above, the `Save` method was already performing the `Add` operation, so it won't actually be updating records at all. This code for `Save` should actually perform the following sequence of steps:

1. detect if the provided value already exists in the database
2. Add the record if it does not exist
3. or Update the existing record if there is one

The schema and `DbContext` implementations have not been provided, so we can't offer a definitive solution here, if you are using a simple integer based `Id` key, then we could use the common convention of checking for a zero value in the `Id`:

```
public static void Save(TProjekty project)
{
    if (project == null) return;

    EntitiesModel em = DB.GetDB();
    if (project.Id > 0)
    {
        em.TProjektys.Attach(project);
        em.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    else
    {
        em.TProjektys.Add(project);
    }
    em.SaveChanges();

    Checker.CheckAfterEverySave();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You shoul use Generic like in your code example.

The signature for the Add method should be :

```
public void Add<TProjekty>(TProjekty data)
  {
     //get db and use add method
  }
```

Comment: Yea I got into this too, but unfortunately I cant use EntitiesFramework.core so db is impossible . Or can you please clarify how should I do it? 
Because this school project is for the .Net Framework 4.8 :(

Comment: Did you use Database First as Database creation method ?

Comment: Yes I did. I have full model in the VS.